# The test project(mocha+axios+chai) is independent, how to count the server code coverage

Tags: express, mocha.js, code-coverage, chai, nyc

There are two projects now. Test project A uses mocha + axios + chai, and the Server project uses node express.
Now I want to count how much coverage can be achieved by Server project B when running test project A

Project A(Testing Project)

```js
import axios from 'axios';
describe('Base API', () => {
  it('is healthy', async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('/hello');

    expect(res, 204);
  });
});
```

Project B(Server Project)

```js
import express from 'express';

const baseRouter = express.Router();

baseRouter.get('/hello',(_req, next) => next(204));

export default baseRouter;
```

how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Project B(Server Project) uses `nyc node.`  to start the server.

Project A(Testing Project) executes the testing case with HTTP as usual.

Shout down Project B(Server Project) that you will see the code coverage report.

shout down project A:

1. Ctrl + C
2. the last API called Project A(Testing Project) will execute the process. exit(0), the exit code as you decide